# Converting NFA to DFA with epsilon

Tags: automata, finite-automata

i'm currently converting this NFA:
[image]

into DFA, however it's a bit confusing and my result so far ended with:
[image: DFA]

However, this doesn't seem right to me, and i would love to hear if im on the right track or not

Comment: Check out this well written article on converting epsilon-NFA to DFA https://www.dennis-grinch.co.uk/tutorial/enfa-to-dfa.